# How can I map a one-to-one hibernate entity with a one-to-many database structure?

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, one-to-one

I'm trying to do a one-to-one bi-directional hibernate entity.  When I save the parent object it is not filling in the customer_id on the child object.  I can't figure out why.  I'm hoping there is some way to tell it to do this through a hibernate annotation.

My Entities look like

```
@Table(name = "customer")
public class CustomerEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private CustomerAddressEntity customerAddress;

    ..more
}
```

and

```
@Table(name="customer_address")
@GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy="increment")
public class CustomerAddressEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence_customer_address_id", strategy = "com.abc.enrollment.service.IdGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_customer_address_id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CustomerEntity customer;

    ..more
}
```

the tables looks like

```
CREATE TABLE enroll.customer_address(
id                 NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
customer_id        NUMBER(38,0) )

CREATE TABLE enroll.customer (
id                 NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL)
```

hibernateVersion = "5.0.0.CR2"

---

In addition to the accepted answer I had to do a few other things that got it working.  I'll post it here in case it helps someone else.  We use lombok and are doing JSON serialization on the object.  The following annotations avoided the stack overflow error.

```
@ToString(exclude = "customer")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "customer")
public class CustomerAddressEntity {
```

and

```
@JsonIgnore
private CustomerEntity customer;
```

Comment: Shouldn't Hibernate reflect the underlying schema?  Should be 1:many as well.

Comment: That is my backup plan, but it will require a lot of work on the front-end and I would rather avoid that if possible.  I feel like this is a valid one-to-one database structure, but perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: The front end should not be affected by your persistence scheme.  Feels like it's an agreement between your Java middle tier and the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a bi-directional relation, you should set it at both ends. Meaning, set the reference to the child object in parent and also the reference to the parent object in child. It should work then.
Something like this

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
CustomerAddress custAddr = new CustomerAddress();
cust.setCustomerAddress( custAddr );
custAddr.setCustomer( cust );
```

Comment: I had to do a few other things to get it working, but this answer set me on the right path.